# CrossPlatform Multiprocessing and Multithreading Library for C++

Tags: c++, multiprocessing

Anybody have an idea of best CrossPlatform Multiprocessing and Multithreading Library for C++. The one i can find by google is OPEN MP. is that the only one and standard library for multiprocessing in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[OpenThreads](http://openthreads.sourceforge.net/)** is a good option.

**[Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html)** is an cross platform, multithreading library and it will be an [part of upcoming C++11 standard](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-library-concurrency).  **[Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/index.html)** exists, but is not yet part of the official boost library.

Also, **[QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)**/**[QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)** from Qt is another good option. It is available on platforms: Linux, Mac OS X, Windows, Embedded Linux, Windows CE, Symbian, Maemo.

Answer (score 1):

SFML has it's sf::Thread class(also has synchronization classes).http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.2/system-threads.php to compile this link -lsfml-system with gcc and sfml-system.lib with vs.

Answer (score 1):

[POCO library](http://pocoproject.org/features.html).  Has a lot of things including thread and thread synchronization classes, thread pool, work queues, active objects and activities, task management, and timers.  Well written code, well integrated with other library classes.

Well worth a look.